# Express/Passport - I have two forms on the same page, how do I send these to two different passport.authentications.

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I'm having trouble with the routing of my signup / login functions, because I don't have a separate signup or login page.  Both functions can be done (via modals) from the '/'

Is this possible? I could just have seperate '/login' and '/signup' routes, as well as seperate pages, but this would break the functionality of the current modals. And it wouldn't look as cool.

```js
  app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var type     = req.body.type;

    if(type === 'signup'){
      console.log('type is signup')
      passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
      successRedirect: '/teacher',
      failureRedirect: '#',
      failureFlash: true
      });
    }

    if (type === 'login'){
      console.log('type is login')
      passport.authenticate('local-login', {
      successRedirect: '/teacher',
      failureRedirect: '/',
      failureFlash: true
      })
    }

  });
```

```html
<div id="modal-signup" class="modal">
  <!-- show any messages that come back with authentication -->
  <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
  <% $('#createLoginButton').preventDefault(); %>
  <% } %>
    <form id="signupForm" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="modal-content">
          <h4 style="color:teal" class="text-teal">Sign Up</h4>
                    <!-- show any messages that come back with authentication -->
  <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
  <% } %>
            <P><label>Username:</label><input type="text" name="signupUsername"/></P>
            <P><label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="signupPassword"/></P>
            <input type="hidden" value="signup" name="type"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" id="createLoginButton" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Create Your Login</a>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
    </div>

      <div id="modal-login" class="modal">
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <div class="modal-content">
          <h4 style="color:teal" class="text-teal">Log In</h4>
            <P><label>Username:</label><input type="text" id="signupUsername"/></P>
            <P><label>Password:</label><input type="password" id="signupPassword"/></P>
            <input type="hidden" value="login" name="type"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#!"  id="loginButton" onclick="submit" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Login</a>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why can't you use different routes since you're just making an AJAX call to login?

Answer (score 0):

Chris makes a good point, you could just use different routes since the AJAX call goes to login, however you can accomplish this the way you are doing it.

You can call passport like this:

```
passport.authenticate('local-login', {
      successRedirect: '/teacher',
      failureRedirect: '/',
      failureFlash: true
      })(req, res);
```